# How can I call woocommerce action inside callback of custom ajax action in wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to customize the default checkout form of woocommerce in my WordPress website.
I have created on custom button and added an ajax call to the button to fetch some data from third party service using API call.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is based on the API response I need to create some custom checkout fields and when I'm adding an `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook inside an callback of ajax it's not working. It seems like this is not the correct approach to trigger woocommerce hooks with ajax call.

Can anyone suggest how can I call woocommerce hooks inside the callback function of ajax or is there any approach to make it work?

P.S: I tried to hide/unhide the fields using JQuery because the created custom fields are required and only hiding fields using JQuery is handling client side validation so it's throwing an error on form submission.

Any help is Appreciated!

Comment: The only way is to add your custom checkout fields with an additional class that will hide them via some CSS. Then your Ajax call response will do the job unhidding them with some Javascript ...

Comment: Thanks for you revert @LoicTheAztec, But when I'm hiding the required fields it's not allowing to submit the form because of server side validations were there.

Comment: I don't really catch… Can you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)